# How to remove orphaned s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket that I can see in the console or with `aws s3 ls`/`aws s3api list-buckets` but the bucket appears to be in some sort of orphaned state.

It's [missing the Access and Region fields in the s3 console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdcFf.png) and I can't access anything about the bucket from the AWS CLI, e.g.:

```
$ aws s3api get-bucket-policy --bucket <my bucket>

An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the GetBucketPolicy operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

I am unable to delete the bucket in the console (there appear to be some 404s in the network tab when clicking 'Confirm' on the delete screen) and I am unable to delete the bucket from the CLI:

```
$ aws s3api delete-bucket --bucket <my bucket>

An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the DeleteBucket operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

Has anyone seen something like this before? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: The issue appeared to resolve itself (the orphan bucket was removed and the bucket name was released) about 7 hours after it started.

Comment: I'm having the same issue today. I'll check back in 7 hours